# How to send attachment using AWS SeS raw message and java

Tags: java, email, aws-lambda

I have seen previous question but they make use of java mail api along with aws,but I need implementation solely using rawmessage. Following code I have written so far.It send the mail and create file without data being populated .Any help is appreciated.

I don't know how to attach file in general,example provided by aws doc,they simply write in file rather than attaching from file provided as parameter.
AWS doc link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleemail/AmazonSimpleEmailService.html#sendEmail-com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendEmailRequest-

```
String data="From: "+from+"\r\nTo: "+to+"\r\nSubject:"+subject+"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\r\n\r\n--NextPart\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"+message+"\r\n\r\n--NextPart\r\nContent-Type: "+Files.probeContentType(Paths.get(res1.getPath()))+";\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"attachment.xlsx\"\n\n"+new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(res1.getPath())))+"\n\n--NextPart--";

SendRawEmailRequest request = new SendRawEmailRequest().withRawMessage(new RawMessage().withData(ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes())));
```

Comment: You need to add more details like what is the output, what is the error log you are getting when you send it.

Comment: I don't get any error,it create the file but content remain empty,I want to set the content of the attached file

Comment: You need to read up on how mime works. What you're asking is on how to send a `Raw` email request, you would need to handle the encoding etc yourself.